# Is there a way to do `arity::try_unary_elementwise` for `ArrayChunked`?

Tags: rust-polars

I'm trying to create a polars extension, and I want one of the functions to return a `pl.Array` type column, however I'm having trouble constructing `ArrayChunked` using familiar functions such as `arity::try_unary_elementwise`. I suspect that many of the convenience functions are implemented for non-Nested `PolarsDataType`s. An example:

```rust
// ArrayRef == Box<dyn Array>
fn string_to_array(s: Option<&str>) -> PolarsResult<Option<ArrayRef>> {
    unimplemented!()
}

// #[polars_expr(output_type_func=array_float_output)]
pub fn convert_to_array(
    s: &[Series]
) -> PolarsResult<Series> {
    let ca = s[0].str()?;

    // ArrayChunked == ChunkedArray<FixedSizeListType>
    let out: ArrayChunked = arity::try_unary_elementwise(
        ca,
        string_to_array
    )?;
    
    Ok(out.into_series())
}
```

This yields the following build error:

```
let out: ArrayChunked = arity::try_unary_elementwise(
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ArrayFromIter<Option<Box<(dyn pyo3_polars::export::polars_core::utils::polars_arrow::array::Array + 'static)>>>` is not implemented for `FixedSizeListArray`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `ArrayFromIter<T>`:
             <BinaryArray<i64> as ArrayFromIter<Option<T>>>
             <BinaryArray<i64> as ArrayFromIter<T>>
             <BooleanArray as ArrayFromIter<bool>>
             <BooleanArray as ArrayFromIter<Option<bool>>>
             <PrimitiveArray<T> as ArrayFromIter<Option<T>>>
             <PrimitiveArray<T> as ArrayFromIter<T>>
             <Utf8Array<i64> as ArrayFromIter<Option<T>>>
             <Utf8Array<i64> as ArrayFromIter<T>>
note: required by a bound in `try_unary_elementwise`
```

Now I understand the error, which has to do with the fact that `ChunkedArray::try_from_chunk_iter` is not implemented for this data type. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I've dug through all the relevant code, especially `chunked_array/from.rs`. I've also copied and tried multiple variations of the inner code of `arity::try_unary_elementwise`, and also I've tried changing the output type of `string_to_array`. Unfortunately no success so far